# PHPUnit Hangs on Assert

Tags: php, phpunit

Everytime an assert fails in my PHP code, the PHPUnit command line hangs for ever. I expected it will show the error (assert) and move on to the next test. Is that not expected?

Here is my code:

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testSomething()
    {
        // send async request
        // wait for request to complete
        $this->assert(<something>);
    }
}
```

phpunit just sits there forever when  is false. I tried different kind of asserts to no help.

PHPUnit config is pretty simple actually.

```
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="name">
            <file>tests/ATest.php</file>
            <file>tests/BTest.php</file>
            <file>tests/CTest.php</file>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>src</directory>
        </whitelist>
        <blacklist>
            <directory>src/models</directory>
        </blacklist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

The assert is also nothing special.
For example, checking if some string is non-empty.

```
$this->assert("" !== $model->getId(), "ID is required.")
```

Comment: Your assumption about moving on should be correct normally. Could you maybe give the actual assert your doing, and maybe also post your configuration for PHPUnit?

Comment: Does it complete the test in the end? Could you run with extra debug (--debug) and/or verbosity (--verbose)? Could you test with the assert "" !== "foo" to rule out $model->getId() being the cause?

Comment: I stepped over after the assert, and found something interesting. It goes to \React\Promise\RejectedPromise#then catch Exception. I think I need to add this since it seems relevant now: the assert is within a promise. I still have no idea why this would happen. Sorry, I am new to PHP, so need to brush on the basics.